# When I run my C# application, Visual Studio reports that it has loaded a managed binary with (what looks like) a randomly generated name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, managed

When I run my C# application, Visual Studio reports that it has loaded a managed binary with (what looks like) a randomly generated name.

For example:

```
'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'ehmgcsw7'
```

or:

```
'WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'jvo4sksu'
```

What is this, and why is its name (seemingly) randomly generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are usually the assemblies generated to provide XML (de)serialization functionality when no pre-compiled serialization assembly as been built.

Comment: Thanks; that was it. I couldn't decide whose to mark as the answer so I did yours, as you answered a whole 7 seconds before Rewinder did.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably using an XmlSerializer somewhere. This might dynamically generate and re-compile code, which in turn results in assemblies with random names that will be loaded. You could step through your code and determine at which point the assemblies are loaded.